# Selenium iedriver not running on IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, driver

Selenium iedriver not running on IE 8 When I run this from command line it pops up but does not runn.. is it the IEdriver which I got and put it in the Selenium Server folder is not calling on it?  Error has occurred in the script on this page.

java -jar c:\SeleniumServer\selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -multiwindow -htmlSuite "*iexplore" "https://www.msn.com" "C:\Test\suite.html" "C:\Test\results.html"

Answer (score 0):

I have only run the IEdriver through VS2012 Console Apps, but in my experience I have had issues similar to the one that you're describing because the IE securities are not all the same.
On IE10 this is found under Internet options > Security Tab, and then ensuring that ALL four zones (Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted Sites, Restricted Sites) are either checked or unchecked to enable protected mode... if one or more of them are different form the others then the driver will fail.

Additionally, I believe (anyone can correct me if I'm wrong) that selenium is updated to run best on the latest versions of the browser. You may want to consider upgrading to IE10 if not, at least IE9.